# Undefined default value for custom accounts fields

Tags: account, default-value, ruby-on-rails

I have a custom field in accounts section of salesforce. As far as I have seen under its configuration, there is no default value set for this field but whenever a new account is created, the value is $70 and it remains same throughout because my code isn't updating this value. Is there any other place where default value for a field can be defined ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: did u check if there's any process builder or workflow field update action updating the field ?

Comment: Did you try checking the debug log ? Put your name in the log and create a new account and see if somewhere in the log this value is getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Account Triggers.The value might be inserted through trigger.

Comment: there are no triggers defined under setup->customize->accounts->triggers. Any other place where I can get it ?

Comment: seem complicated,have you check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77766/how-to-check-whether-fields-are-being-used-or-not-in-sandbox ?

Comment: no clue, I have checked my entire codebase, there is no use of that API name